# Add Column Header to Data Tables

Tags: c#, .net

I am looping over the workbooks in a folder and importing multiple excel worksheets from them into a SQL database, but only the first sheet of each workbook has column headers.

I'm attempting to create a header row on all sheets except the first sheet by inserting a blank row into row 0  but I can't work out how to add the values into that row to make the header.

The values should be `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Country`

Any help would be appreciated.

```cs
SQLConnection.Open();
using (SqlBulkCopy BC = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLConnection))
{
    BC.DestinationTableName = SchemaName + "." + TableName;
    foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
    BC.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

    DataRow blankRow = dt.NewRow();

    for (int temp = 0; temp < 3; temp++)
    {
        blankRow[temp] = "";
    }
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(blankRow, 0);

    BC.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Comment: What's the current result and what do you expect?

Comment: Currently I'm only getting the data to import if I add headers manually.  I would like an automated way to do that as there can be 5 workbooks with up to 8 tabs in each with rows totaling around 2 million..   .

Comment: it's really not clear what the question is here. just a guess: are you using ExportDataTable? did you specify ExportColumnName = true?

Comment: Each file has the headers for all the data listed in the first tab? Why don't you just set those to a variable and track them? I think you need more context in your code. What is `dt`? Give examples in your question, not here in the comments though.

Comment: dt is Data Table, this is just a snipet of the code it seemed to long to post and this is the only bit I have an issue with.

Comment: Full code here:http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/04/c-import-multiple-excel-files-with.html

Comment: That code has no reference to `temp` or `blankRow` where is the code for `temp` and what are you trying to do with it? What is the actual setup of the workbooks, that code demands Excel Tables, it sounds like you don't have that

Comment: I found the code to add a row elsewhere when i was trying to find a solution to my problem.  The full  code works great to import 2 million records in under a minute to the database but onlt if I go into each sheet and add a header row.  I also tried to set HDR to "No" but I got an error "The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination."

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to add the vales to the blank columns I created but it didn't solve my problem as the blank row didn't go into the top row of each sheet.

```
                            `DataRow blankRow = dt.NewRow();

                            for (int temp = 0; temp < 3; temp++)
                            {
                                blankRow[temp] = "";
                            }
                            dt.Rows.InsertAt(blankRow, 0);

                            blankRow[0] = "First_Name";
                            blankRow[1] = "Last_Name";
                            blankRow[2] = "Country";`
```